# Enlarge the Image in full view mode after tap on image in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to design a view where there is image in small view when i tap on that image i want to enlarge that image in full view in xamarin forms like in whats app when we change the profile pic of application . we saw image in small section then after clicking on image it shows in full section and we got options for edit image ...which views should i used?
Anybody know how i can achieve this

```
  <Image x:Name="image1" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could click on the image and than show a custom dialog with an enlarged picture of it.( you pass the url/base64string between the dialog and main screen).

For the custom dialog part you could use: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: thanx for ur rply .....but i dont want to show popup it should be like page only...just as in whats app when we try to change our profile picture we go to setting and then we click that small profile icon it switch to large image with edit icon....similar to this i am trying to implement

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You want a small image showing and when they click on that image it enlarges in the page itself? If that's what you want you could enlarge the imageview in program code or you could use 2 imageviews which one is invisible.

Comment: hmm....u were correct i need to display popup which covers the entire page and feel like use is at new page

Comment: Okay, don't forget to mark this answer as correct than ;).
If you have questions about the popup plugin, u can ask them here, i'm currently using the popup myself.

Comment: If i want to fill this popup as page i need to place back button and title on the top ...have any idea about it

Comment: I'm kinda confused what you mean, you want the popup to fill the entire page ? if so wouldn't it be better to just use a normal page? For the backbutton do you mean the hardware backbutton? if so you can override it for your popup page ( it says in description). For title you have to make one yourself in XAML code as I don't think it's possible to show a title( maybe check his examples)

Comment: In ur demo app there is one popup SystemOffsetPage ....look at this to close the popup there is button ....so i m also trying same think nly difference is want to place this close button on the top with back button image

Comment: You can put on top just by using XAML code. Or do u mean placing it in the titlebar? I don't think that's possible since the titlebar is from the page behind.
For placing it at the top: put a stacklayout with verticaloptions startandend ( or something similar to this)